# Unable to access Istio addons via network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, istio, istio-kiali, istio-prometheus

All add-ons are running fine, just I am unable to access it via Network LoadBalancer URL

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 ~]$ kubectl get vs,dr,gw -n istio-system
NAME                                               GATEWAYS               HOSTS                                                                                                          AGE
virtualservice.networking.istio.io/grafana-vs      [grafana-gateway]      [grafana.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.u                  s-east-1.amazonaws.com]      32h
virtualservice.networking.istio.io/kiali-vs        [kiali-gateway]        [kiali.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-                  east-1.amazonaws.com]        32h
virtualservice.networking.istio.io/prometheus-vs   [prometheus-gateway]   [prometheus.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.el                  b.us-east-1.amazonaws.com]   32h
virtualservice.networking.istio.io/tracing-vs      [tracing-gateway]      [tracing.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.u                  s-east-1.amazonaws.com]      32h

NAME                                             HOST         AGE
destinationrule.networking.istio.io/grafana      grafana      32h
destinationrule.networking.istio.io/kiali        kiali        32h
destinationrule.networking.istio.io/prometheus   prometheus   32h
destinationrule.networking.istio.io/tracing      tracing      32h

NAME                                             AGE
gateway.networking.istio.io/grafana-gateway      32h
gateway.networking.istio.io/kiali-gateway        32h
gateway.networking.istio.io/prometheus-gateway   32h
gateway.networking.istio.io/tracing-gateway      32h
```

My source code where I kept the YAML files is below;

```
https://github.com/ameyaagashe/istio-addons.git
```

Pods are running fine, so is the case with service is fine as per below;

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ kubectl get pods,svc -n istio-system
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/grafana-94f5bf75b-5vmwk                 1/1     Running   0          37h
pod/istio-egressgateway-64f6cf8c5c-xfx5c    1/1     Running   0          37h
pod/istio-ingressgateway-7d494fc944-nfbgl   1/1     Running   0          37h
pod/istiod-559cbd785d-rxs5m                 1/1     Running   0          37h
pod/jaeger-5c7675974-2tkg9                  1/1     Running   0          37h
pod/kiali-667b888c56-2p9rt                  1/1     Running   0          32h
pod/prometheus-7d76687994-7b8hp             2/2     Running   0          33h

NAME                           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
service/grafana                ClusterIP      10.100.217.154   <none>                                                                    3000/TCP                                                                     37h
service/istio-egressgateway    ClusterIP      10.100.124.234   <none>                                                                    80/TCP,443/TCP,15443/TCP                                                     37h
service/istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.100.139.212   a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-1680121350.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   15021:32196/TCP,80:30819/TCP,443:31500/TCP,31400:30624/TCP,15443:31551/TCP   37h
service/istiod                 ClusterIP      10.100.49.147    <none>                                                                    15010/TCP,15012/TCP,443/TCP,15014/TCP                                        37h
service/jaeger-collector       ClusterIP      10.100.117.234   <none>                                                                    14268/TCP,14250/TCP                                                          37h
service/kiali                  ClusterIP      10.100.158.203   <none>                                                                    20001/TCP,9090/TCP                                                           37h
service/prometheus             ClusterIP      10.100.40.238    <none>                                                                    9090/TCP                                                                     37h
service/tracing                ClusterIP      10.100.50.33     <none>                                                                    80/TCP                                                                       37h
service/zipkin                 ClusterIP      10.100.183.114   <none>                                                                    9411/TCP                                                                     37h
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$
```

Now, I cannot access them ...

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ curl http://grafana.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: grafana.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ curl http://kiali.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: kiali.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ curl http://prometheus.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: prometheus.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ curl http://tracing.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: tracing.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$
```

P. S; Please check my screenshot below,
[image]

So now, I should update my NLM string in each YAML file with a77* to learningservicemesh.com ?

Please assist.

Did exactly as you suggested but no charm...

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ kubectl get vs,gw,dr -n istio-system
NAME                                               GATEWAYS               HOSTS                                  AGE
virtualservice.networking.istio.io/grafana-vs      [grafana-gateway]      [grafana.learningservicemesh.com]      6s
virtualservice.networking.istio.io/kiali-vs        [kiali-gateway]        [kiali.learningservicemesh.com]        6s
virtualservice.networking.istio.io/prometheus-vs   [prometheus-gateway]   [prometheus.learningservicemesh.com]   6s
virtualservice.networking.istio.io/tracing-vs      [tracing-gateway]      [tracing.learningservicemesh.com]      6s

NAME                                             AGE
gateway.networking.istio.io/grafana-gateway      6s
gateway.networking.istio.io/kiali-gateway        6s
gateway.networking.istio.io/prometheus-gateway   6s
gateway.networking.istio.io/tracing-gateway      6s

NAME                                             HOST         AGE
destinationrule.networking.istio.io/grafana      grafana      6s
destinationrule.networking.istio.io/kiali        kiali        6s
destinationrule.networking.istio.io/prometheus   prometheus   6s
destinationrule.networking.istio.io/tracing      tracing      6s
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ curl http://grafana.learningservicemesh.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: grafana.learningservicemesh.com
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ curl http://kiali.learningservicemesh.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: kiali.learningservicemesh.com
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ curl http://prometheus.learningservicemesh.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: prometheus.learningservicemesh.com
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$ curl http://tracing.learningservicemesh.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: tracing.learningservicemesh.com
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-60 addons]$
```

Comment: maybe you need to wait the dns propagation :)

Comment: How long for?  It is like 12 hours now easily?

Comment: nslookup tracing.a77a61e85b85a46198645ac29a1ebbfd-e856e794d398b3ae.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 8.8.8.8

Comment: you need to have a dns zone and create cname records that point to your ELB

Comment: Please check my question again and the next line of action?

Comment: Can you check [here](https://medium.com/cloud-native-the-gathering/istio-ingress-to-expose-your-k8s-services-via-individual-dns-2ec9c2717b81) if you've configured everything properly? Can you check if any addon will work with `learningservicemesh.com` as host in gateway and virtual service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was, subdomain was not created for learningservicemesh.com. Once I created a sub-domain, all started working perfectly fine.